# Why does Bane ask only one guy to stay in the plane wreckage in Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

From the [opening scene in the Dark Knight Rises](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WomtYMqeAe8) we learn that Bane and two other members of the League of Shadows get in the plane. The CIA agent tells them that *his flight plan includes only **one** of them*. Then he starts interrogating them, near the plane's open door. The one who talks first gets *a ticket in the plane*, but Bane calls him on his bluff (*why shoot someone you're just going to throw from a plane?*)

After the League of Shadows attack, when they are leaving the plane Bane asks **one** guy to stay

> No! They expect **one** of us in the wreckage, brother.

Bane obviously knew the CIA agent was bluffing, and even if not, after his mask was taken off he must have seen that the three League of Shadows members are still *on board* (as a LoS member, I'm pretty sure Bane *has learned to mind his surroundings*). So, the flight plan must, or could have, included three other unexpected guys, not just one. If the flight plan had included the three, the absence of two bodies could have told authorities much more than having two extra ones...

Why then ask only **one** guy to stay? Why not ask **three** and play it safe?

Comment: There are so many other problems with how they disabled the plane and crew that would be huge red flags for any investigation team, that even three missing bodies would hardly be the biggest concern.

Comment: It is my assumption that the writers simply wanted to show the audience the amount of respect/power that Bane had. Being able to tell a man to voluntarily end himself, and have that man then go through with the act, sets the precedence for his character very early on. A truely in depth and logical reason is not needed to make this point clear, just a mostly believeable one.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero, best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You answered your own question.  As the CIA officer clearly states, the flight plan only includes one member of the LoA, not three.  If Bane had ordered more than one of them to stay, it would have been suspicious.  The flight plan calls for one extra passenger, yet here are three extra passengers.  Something obviously went down.

I think that it was a better safe than sorry type thing. As you said, Bane didn't know if he was telling the truth or not, there was a 50/50 chance that he was. For all Bane knew, none of them were on the flight plan, but he was using his judgement based off of what he was told, which was that only one of them was added to the plan, so, he told only one to stay just to be safe. There's also the fact that if Bane had ordered all of them to stay, his forces would have been that much weaker.

Even if, though, the CIA guy was bluffing and the plane hadn't crashed, it would be much easier for the agent to explain why there are so many more passengers as opposed to them looking at the plane and wondering why all these other bodies are on the plane, which would still cause them to become suspicious. Not to mention, Bane also removed one passenger from the plane, so there's also the possibility that he didn't believe the CIA agent at all and was replacing a body with a body, which would have the investigation into the crash account for all the passengers.

Comment: How could Bane know for sure? Why is the CIA agent not actually throwing them out of the plane? What the CIA agent says doesn't agree with what he does. So I don't get why Bane trust that statement that there is only one. Bane also sees the other members of the LoS on board when his mask is removed...

Comment: I think that it was a better safe than sorry type thing.  As you said, Bane didn't know if he was telling the truth or not, there was a 50/50 chance that he was.  For all Bane knew, none of them were on the flight plan, but he was using his judgement based off of what he was told, which was that only one of them was added to the plan, so, he told only one to stay just to be safe.  There's also the fact that if Bane had ordered all of them to stay, his forces would have been that much weaker

Comment: Even if, though, the CIA guy was bluffing and the plane hadn't crashed, it would be much easier for the agent to explain why there are so many more passengers as opposed to them looking at the plane and wondering why all these other bodies are on the plane, which would still cause them to become suspicious.  Not to mention, Bane also removed one passenger from the plane, so there's also the possibility that he didn't believe the CIA agent at all and was replacing a body with a body, which would have the investigation into the crash account for all the passengers.

Comment: I actually was thinking about that and to put a community-wiki answer with that. If you can add that you your answer I'll accept it. Two bodies can be missing in the wreckage or its disappearance be an unsolved mystery. It won't necessarily point to the LoS. Two extra bodies raises a lot of red flags...

Comment: I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Just a note 2 years later: "Bane also removed one passenger from the plane, so there's also the possibility that he didn't believe the CIA agent at all and was replacing a body with a body" wouldn't make sense since we seen Bane already replace the body of the scientists with the cadaver who had some of the scientists blood transfused into him.

Answer (score 2):

Bane didn't think the CIA officer was bluffing.  He was merely criticizing the CIA officer's use of a bullet, in means of throwing the interrogator off their game.

Comment: Correct. Bane also couldn't have been aware that the plane was flying so close to the ground that they could easily have survived the fall (as long as they didn't land on a rock) which is probably why CIA was going to shoot him.

Comment: @CrowTRobot With hands tied and a bag over their head, I doubt it'd be easy to survive a fall out of an airplane.

Comment: Nevertheless, when he mask is removed from Bane's head he is able to see that **no one** has been thrown off the plane. So even if he was only _ criticizing_, Bane should have been aware that CIA agent's flight plan _might_ actually included 3 and not 1 passengers more. Asking just one guy to stay could have jeopardized the whole plan.

Comment: I seriously doubt that there was an official flight plan, much less mention how many people "extra" there were, given the thing was a CIA black-op.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, that's a possible answer. Still, Bane wanted/commanded **one** LoS member on the wreckage.

Comment: @Deion: Bane knew the actual flight plan, filed with the actual CIA.

Comment: Strongly disagree. The clear implication is that Bane knows the CIA officer was bluffing about executing the men. He WAS throwing off Littlefing- uh, the CIA agent, but by pointing out that he wasn't fooling anyone, and he felt in control.